# phpMyAdmin: can't set specific foreign key, even though types are the same

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My list_items table has the following columns

- `ListID`
- `WordID`

My lists table has a primary, auto-incremented primary key `ListID`. I want to make the `ListID` in list_items a foreign key referencing the primary key in lists, but I get an error:

> **Error creating foreign key on `ListID` (check data types).**

Both columns are int(8), and both table types are InnoDB. What could possibly be the issue?

Following [these instructions](http://www.binarytides.com/blog/create-foreign-key-using-phpmyadmin/) has worked fine in setting up other foreign keys.

The only thing I can think of is on phpMyAdmin's main screen, there's a message:

> "The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated. To find out why click here."

But wouldn't any issue there prevent me from setting up other foreign keys?

Relevant SQL:

````
--
-- Table structure for table `lists`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lists` (
  ```ListID``` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ```UserID``` int(8) NOT NULL,
  ```privacy``` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  ```name``` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  ```description``` text NOT NULL,
  ```date created``` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ```date modified``` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (```ListID```),
  KEY ```UserID``` (```UserID```)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lists`
--

--
-- Table structure for table `list_items`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_items` (
  ```ListID``` int(8) NOT NULL,
  ```WordID``` int(8) NOT NULL,
  KEY ```ListID``` (```ListID```),
  KEY ```WordID``` (```WordID```)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `list_items`
--

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  ```UserID``` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ```email``` int(50) NOT NULL,
  ```username``` int(25) NOT NULL,
  ```password``` int(25) NOT NULL,
  ```join date``` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (```UserID```)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
````

Comment: We need to see the table structure to help you.

Comment: Is there a designated place to post screenshots, or do I need to set up a Flickr account?

Comment: You can use what you want. You can use free image hosting too or just export the sql statement that will create your tables.

Comment: I've appended the SQL to the question.

Comment: Side note - space in column names are nothing but a royal pain in the ... - do you really need them?

Comment: Nope, I took them out and replaced them with underscores. My book said it wouldn't matter as long as you added backticks, but apparently that screws with stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an awful lot of backticks in your sql 
normally you would only have 1 set, that could be causing a problem

example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_items` (
  `ListID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `WordID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  KEY `ListID` (`ListID`),
  KEY `WordID` (`WordID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: This correct. The problem is being caused by the backticks in the field names. Not sure exactly why, but eliminating them fixes the issue.

Comment: I removed add the quotes too before my testing

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I removed the backticks like you recommended and everything's working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it manually with this the below at the foreign key was created fine

```
ALTER TABLE list_items ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_ListID (ListID) REFERENCES lists(ListID);
```